# How can i solve the auto souce code in ckeditor from Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

When i use ckeditor in laravel from my localhost and every post i made, that comes with source code and how can i stop this.

I am new!

{{Form::label('body', 'body')}}
{{Form::textarea('body', '', ['id' => 'article-ckeditor','class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Body Text'])}}

When i save my body like : This is Good and nice but actually

**This is Good and nice**

this text coming with source code.

Answer (score 0):

Hy you can use the `{!! $name->name !!}`  insted of `{{ $name->name }}`